# My responsive layout is not responding

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am attempting to implement a responsive layout based on the exmaples and code here: [www.responsivegridsystem.com](http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/)

I have wrapped it a couple of containers as I need a `960px` content area centered in a `1000px` container.

My intent is that with a width smaller then `960px`, both containers just become 100% width. The layout is exactly what I want at full size, but it is not shifting like I want when smaller then 960px.

Current CSS (with some edits based on suggestions, still not working.):

```
.masterContainer {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:-10px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    width:1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.pageContainer {
    position:relative;
    display:table;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:960px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }


/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.group:after {
    clear:both;
}
.group {
    zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */
}

/*  GRID OF THREE  */
.span_3_of_3 {
    width: 100%;
}
.span_2_of_3 {
    width: 70%;
}
.span_1_of_3 {
    width: 30%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px and max-width: 960px) {
    .masterContainer {
        width:100%;
    }
    .pageContainer {
        width:100%; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span_3_of_3 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span_2_of_3 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span_1_of_3 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="masterContainer">
    <div class="pageContainer">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="col span_3_of_3" id="header">Header
            </div>
            <div class="col span_3_of_3" id="slideshowContainer">Slideshow
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section group">
            <div class="col span_2_of_3" id="contentArea">
            This is column 1
            </div>
            <div class="col span_1_of_3" id="rightColumn">
            This is column 2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col span_3_of_3" id="footer">Footer
        </div>
        <div class="col span_3_of_3" id="bottom">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is something wrong with my @media code or did I break it somewhere else?

Comment: I'm not seeing any @media queries in your css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your media queries are telling IDs to do something, while your HTML has them as classes. Change it to something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:960px){
    .masterContainer {width: 100%;}
    .pageContainer {width: 100%;}
}
```

Here is a fiddle with your code and the query. I gave them background colors for the example.

[JS Fiddle with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/K6s6z/)

Comment: Media queries added, i just missed them when pasting into the question.

Comment: Your media queries are currently telling IDs to do something, but your containers are classes in your html.

Comment: Gah! you are totally right, i swear i thought those were id's. HOWEVER, I changed the media queries as above, and it still isn't responding.

Comment: Please see the fiddle I added. Why are you setting a min-width in the same query?  According to the description you added, you should just need to set a max-width.

Comment: Well I did that as a stab in the dark it wasn't working without that either. Though if i'm going to have that I will need to add those changes to the max 480 bit as well.

Comment: your fiddle took care of it. took out the min-width and it all seems fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted there is no @media codes... You cannot have a specific width's set if you intened for the page to be responsive ex. `masterContainer width 1000px`.. youll need to redo that for example:

```
@media (min-width: 700px), handheld and (orientation: landscape) 
{
   .masterContainer{
     width:60%; // or whatever you may need
   }
}
```

have a look at some examples.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: added the media statements above, that was just a posting accident

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify it via `@media` queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 959px) {
    .masterContainer,
    .pageContainer {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Media queries added, i just missed them when pasting into the question. Note that the containers are called by id, not class, hence the '#' instead of '.' I have ONLY in mine, should that not be there?

Comment: In your HTML there are classes and even in the first lines of your CSS. You have to decide what is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have media queries in your css.

Create separate files for diffrent screen sizes and put styles in there. Thats the easiest way.

And read this article. It will help you to understand how media queries work.

[csstricks media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: I do have media queries, I failed to paste them into the original question. I have edited it now.

Comment: Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K6s6z/2/ I added borders just for debug purposes

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is this:
`@media only screen and (min-width: 481px and max-width: 960px)` that is a wrong query.

It should be:
`@media screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:960px)`

You can't combine the `min` and `max` like you had it.